# Using Results From Case Statement in INNER JOIN statement in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, join, case, alias

The following is my query:

```
SELECT 
        U.Part
       ,U.EndDate
       ,F.Part
       ,F.EndDate
       ,(U.Calc1/(CASE F.Calc2 WHEN 0 THEN .00000001 ELSE F.Calc2 END)) AS PercentRepaired
       ,(1-(U.Calc1/(CASE F.Calc2 WHEN 0 THEN .00000001 ELSE F.Calc2 END))) AS PercentNoFault
       ,NF.*
       ,R.* 
FROM 
       RCCalc1Part U
INNER JOIN 
       RCCalc2Part F
ON 
       U.Part = F.Part AND U.EndDate = F.EndDate 
INNER JOIN RCNF NF
ON     Part = LEFT(NF.Part,7)
INNER JOIN Repair R
ON
        NF.Part = (CASE LEFT(NF.Part,7) WHEN '2000000' THEN CONCAT(R.Part,'-',LEFT(R.ExtendedPart,1)) ELSE NF.Part END)
ORDER BY 
       U.SN ASC, NF.Part ASC, U.EndDate ASC
```

The following is the INNER JOIN that I am concerned about:

```
INNER JOIN Repair R
ON
        NF.Part = (CASE LEFT(NF.Part,7) WHEN '2000000' THEN CONCAT(R.Part,'-',LEFT(R.ExtendedPart,1)) ELSE NF.Part END)
```

I am trying to use a debugger to find the value of the right side of the `=`.  It doesn't seem to be doing what I want it to.  When NF. Part = `2000000` then I want to `CONCAT` `R.Part` and want that concatenation to be the value on the right side of the `=`.

Am I doing this right?  If not...am I far off?

Thanks.

Comment: Its not entirely clear what you are trying to do but I would just run the case statement by itself until it looks how you want it

Comment: `INNER JOIN Repair R
ON
        NF.Part = (CASE LEFT(NF.Part,7) WHEN '2000000' THEN CONCAT(R.Part,'-',LEFT(R.ExtendedPart,1)) ELSE R.Part END)`   was what I was looking for....everything was right except the column after the else statement.  Debugged using your method.

Comment: Nice, I was actually going to point out that your else was returning NF.Part but I wasn't sure if that was intentional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INNER JOIN Repair R ON NF.Part = (CASE LEFT(NF.Part,7) WHEN '2000000' THEN CONCAT(R.Part,'-',LEFT(R.ExtendedPart,1)) ELSE R.Part END)` was what I was looking for....everything was right except the column after the else statement.